# Will React-Native eventually support HarmonyOS?

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services, harmonyos

What's going to happen now that Huawei is releasing their new OS? If it blows up, and there's a good chance it will, there'd be a massive gap in access to a whole new platform. I've chosen the easy way out and I've been developing mobile apps for iOS and Android via React-Native. Will React-Native support HarmonyOS?

Comment: Well, Facebook uses React Native and is the primary maintainer and they will need to support HarmonyOS if it "blows up", so I'm guessing yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question might be better directed towards the [React Native Feature Requests](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests) page.

I haven't seen any mentions to add support for HarmonyOS at this stage, however the community could add support if there's demand. There's plenty of [prior art around for alternative platforms](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/out-of-tree-platforms).

If Facebook starts supporting HarmonyOS with its apps, then first-class support is much more likely.

Comment: FWIW, Meituan ported Flutter to HarmonyOS already: https://tech.meituan.com/2021/01/22/flutter-in-harmonyos.html

Answer (score 1):

- I think we need to wait for HarmonyOS become more popular with
  developer & user, currently (Dec 2020), Huawei only shares beta
  testing for a limited partner of them after the HDC event, no more
  technical docs available for HarmonyOS app developers at this time.
- If it becomes more popular & attracts developers, maybe React-Native will support it, For more information, you can find at https://www.huaweicentral.com/harmonyos-hongmeng-os-everything-you-need-to-know/